# Why (and to what purpose) does Scala automatically initialize variables that are unintialized (itentionally)?

Tags: scala, variables, initialization, var

I stumbled upon this and it caused a problem in an OpenGL-application I'm currently writing, so I have to ask:

```
abstract class Entity
{
  protected var modelMatrixLocation: Int = _
  protected var modelViewProjectionMatrixLocation: Int = _
}

class ConcreteEntity extends Entity
{
  modelMatrixLcoation: Int = getUniformLocation(shaderID, "modelMatrix")

  println(modelMatrixLocation)
  println(modelViewProjectionMatrixLocation)
}
```

Concrete Entity prints out

> 0
>
> 0

Now obviously the real world example is a bit more complex, but that's exactly what happened. I got two `Int`s that represent a location of a uniform in a shader and forgot to initialize one.

Then I had to debug quite a bit to find out why my shader was behaving so strangely (while before it worked - which was pure co-incidence as the modelMatrix was never used but the modelViewProjectionMatrix was set, so it all miraculously worked)

So my questions:
1.)
Why is a variable Int that is uninitialized set to 0? (Instead of, for example, -1) I mean, -1 would be more appropriate as it would not collide with SQL-queries, Collection-object-fetching or stuff like that either - in computer science we usually start counting with 0, so -1 would throw us a more obvious error.

2.) How can I avoid this? How can I make sure, that all the variables from the `abstract class Entity` are really filled?

I mean, I could probably do something like:

```
protected var modelMatrixLocationName: String = _
protected val modelMatrixLocation: Int = getUniformLocation(shaderID, "modelMatrixLocationName")
```

with a little bit of tweaking, but that's just ugly.

Another way would be to use `Option` instead. One the one hand this seems to be a nice(r) way to handle this, but still I'd need to use a var, which I'd like to avoid. `val`s all the way! ;)

Any better ideas?

Comment: `_` does not leave variables uninitialised, it explicitly initialises them to their default value, which is 0 for `Int`.

Comment: But there is no way to only `declare` a variable in Scala, is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually initializing them by `_` because you assigning `anything` to them.

To solve your problem you can either not asign anything to those vars (you are in abstract class so you should be able to do that) or use `traits` which are Java's interfaces, but they can contain or functions bodies. In your example the more interesting fact about traits is that, they can hold uninitialized fields.

Comment: `lazy` is not allowed with vars. So how would lazy evaluation help with my problem exactly?

Comment: @Teolha Sry i misunderstood question

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, a trait is not an option here, as entity does hold some constructor-parameters which I omitted in the question. Of course I could add another trait just for the uniforms, but as they more or less belong to the entity ... I will see :)

Comment: scala> null.asInstanceOf[Int]
res0: Int = 0

See the spec, section 6.3
http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#the-null-value

Answer (score 1):

The real reason is that the JVM will need to wipe memory regions before handing them to newly created objects and filling memory with zeroes is something that can be done really quickly. It also nicely coincides with the representation of `null` for references. This has nothing to do with Scala and can therefore also not be avoided.

So, if you want your variables to start out in a known-bad state then replace the `_` with `-1` in your program.

Answer (score 0):

## Why is a variable Int that is uninitialized set to 0

As stated by Lee: The variable is no unitialized. It is initialized with `_`.

So here to why it is 0:
Being compiled to the JVM all values have an initial value, that is defined by the JVM.
So for Integers for example it is `0` for most other classes it is `null`.
If you would use ScalaJS the default values would be the one defined by JavaScript.

## How can I avoid this?

Use a `trait`

```
trait Entity {
  def  modelMatrixLocation: Int
  def modelViewProjectionMatrixLocation: Int
}
```

Comment: Sadly a trait is not an option here, as it does not allow constructor-parameters, which I omitted, but are present in the real application. I'm just wondering why 0 is the default... but I assume it's because it's the identity element for addition... or it's just that the natural numbers start there.